# Saving a graph of a great number of nodes

Tags: graphs-and-networks, export, import

I'm developing a code where I get graphs with over 10K nodes. These graphs have a particular relationship between clustering and degree that I need to save for future analysis. The problem is when I use `EdgeList` and then save the list in a *Mathematica* file (.nb), when I recall it, the size of some communities are different to the ones showed by the graph. The following sizes are obtained after change the graph by the `EdgeList`

```
Community = FindGraphCommunities[g];
aux = Length[#] & /@ FindGraphCommunities[g]
```

> ```
> {1845, 1656, 1536, 1419, 1206, 441, 349, 342, 210, 205, 168, 126, 
>           113, 103, 73, 58, 57, 45, 40, 8}
> ```

Then I use `EdgeList[g]`, click on Show full Output and copy the entire cell and save it into the file.nb. When I call again the graph `g3` from the file.nb it gives me the following sizes

```
g = g3;
Community = FindGraphCommunities[g];
aux = Length[#] & /@ FindGraphCommunities[g]
```

> ```
>  {1884, 1766, 1720, 1364, 643, 420, 420, 394, 266, 218, 211, 159, 117, 
>         101, 93, 76, 29, 28, 24, 21, 20, 16, 10}
> ```

I don't know what happen there, could be the command `EdgeList` or something behind...Then I try to save the graph by Exporting it as a `gml` file and after 10 minutes it was still running... So, do you have any suggestion for this, how can I export efficiently this information or do I have to wait for the exportation in `gml` format?

Comment: You have been a user for 9 months and still don't format your code properly. Please, refer to the documentation centre for code formatting practices.

Comment: @Jotasmall you already asked 3 question, and received good answers for all of them. Yet you did **not** except a single answer. Do you understand how to do it?

Comment: Nope, could you explain me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Graph will not be unique unless you specify some other properties. Here VertexList order is important. Compare:

```
g = RandomGraph[{10^4, 10^6}];

FindGraphCommunities[g] == FindGraphCommunities[Graph[EdgeList[g]]]
```

> False

```
FindGraphCommunities[g] == FindGraphCommunities[Graph[VertexList[g], EdgeList[g]]]
```

> True

So now when you know how to get it right I'd also advise to compress VertexList and EdgeList with Compress or...

...save it as compressed AdjacencyMatrix:

```
g = RandomGraph[{10^4, 10^6}];    
cam = Compress[AdjacencyMatrix[g]];

g == AdjacencyGraph[Uncompress[cam]]
```

> True

```
g === AdjacencyGraph[Uncompress[cam]]
```

> True

`cam` is a string you can save in a notebook or a text file. `FindGraphCommunities` will also give same answer.